# GOCSV mapping to struct with Date/Time: Issue when the field is empty

Tags: csv, datetime, go

**EDIT: I Made a mistake and corrected it**

I'm trying to map a `CSV` file to a struct that defines fields of `time.Datetime` (later I want to change the datetime format to another format).

This is the output of my program

```
❯ go run issue.go                                                                                                                                                 ✗ master
record:  05/02/2019 15:02:31
record:  05/02/2019 16:02:40
record:
record on line 0; parse error on line 4, column 2: parsing time "" as "02/01/2006 15:04:05": cannot parse "" as "02"
1936  -  2019-02-05 15:02:31 +0000 UTC
1937  -  2019-02-05 16:02:40 +0000 UTC
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x10e58cc]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/gtheys/Code/go/src/github.axa.com/KTAXA/claims-headers-poc/issue.go:49 +0x1bc
exit status 2
```

I have tried to execute `time.Parse` using an empty string, it **Didn't work**. So the problem should be here. But I have no idea how to handle it graceful in following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
)

type DateTime struct {
    time.Time
}

type Issue struct {
    NotifyNo   string
    NotifyDate DateTime
}

// Convert the CSV string as internal date
func (date *DateTime) UnmarshalCSV(csv string) (err error) {
    fmt.Println("record: ", csv)
    date.Time, err = time.Parse("02/01/2006 15:04:05", csv)
    return err
}

func main() {
    //const layout = "02/05/2006 15:04:00"
    issuesFile, err := os.OpenFile("ISSUES.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer issuesFile.Close()

    issues := []*Issue{}

    gocsv.SetCSVReader(func(in io.Reader) gocsv.CSVReader {
        r := csv.NewReader(in)
        r.Comma = '|'
        return r // Allows use pipe as delimiter
    })

    if err := gocsv.UnmarshalFile(issuesFile, &issues); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, issue := range issues {
        fmt.Println(issue.NotifyNo, " - ", issue.NotifyDate)
    }

    if _, err := issuesFile.Seek(0, 0); err != nil { // Go to the start of the file
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

the csv input file:

```
NotifyNo|NotifyDate|
1936|05/02/2019 15:02:31|
1937|05/02/2019 16:02:40|
1938||
1951|05/02/2019 17:02:19|
```

Comment: *"I have tried to execute `time.Parse` using an empty string, it worked."* is not consistent with what I'm seeing [here](https://play.golang.com/p/5oMhZXYI4ZZ), are you *certain* it worked for you? Anyway, to fix this simply check if the `csv` string's empty, and if it is then skip the `time.Parse` step and just return `nil`.

Comment: Ok I made a [mistake testing](https://play.golang.com/p/LiKHg1SKugP) So before time.Parse I have to check the type and cast it to a string to make it work? will try it at least